# How to Compare two party lists in CRM 2016

Tags: c#, plugins, crm, dynamics-crm-2016, appointment

I have two Party Lists from required person in Appointment. One from PreEntity and one from PostEntity and i want to compare them in order to find the changes in the person but doesn't work altough the two lists have many common person.

```
  var requiredPreImage = preImage.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("requiredattendees");
  var requiredPostImage = postImage.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("requiredattendees");
  foreach (var required in requiredPreImage.Entities)
  {
     if (!requiredPostImage.Entities.Contains(required))
     {
        SendEmail(); // you have deleted from appointment
     }
  }
```

Comment: Read this https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/archive/2015/09/07/working-with-dynamics-crm-activity-party-lists-in-c-plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is you've assumed Contains is doing something magical that it really isn't doing.  It's just using the standard `Equals` comparison for the `Object` class.  So unless the objects are the same exact reference (and they won't be in this case) it will never find the object in the Entities collection.

You'll need to first just get the list of Ids of the postImage Entities, then search through those by the id:

```
var requiredPreImage = preImage.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("requiredattendees");
var requiredPostImageIds = postImage.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("requiredattendees").Entities.Select(e => e.Id).Distinct().ToDictionary(id => id);
foreach (var required in requiredPreImage.Entities)
{
    if (!requiredPostImageIds.Contains(required.Id))
    {
        SendEmail(); // you have deleted from appointment
    }
}
```